# Redirect 301 of .htaccess didn't redirect correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My redirection in my .htacces doesn't want redirect correct url.

```
DefaultLanguage fr-FR

Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^clic_go\.php\?id=(.+)$ /clic.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

He redirect to :

/?id=4

i want :

/clic.php?id=4

Any idea ?

Thanks you =D

Comment: Try deleting your browser cache, redirect rules can store in the cache and when updated by the .htaccess wont take effect until the cache is cleared

Comment: I've actually tried on many more computer & browser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(.+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^clic_go\.php$ /clic.php?id=%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Because query string is not in the RewriteRule url.

With all the query string, you can just do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^clic_go\.php$ /clic.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

Because without addition, it is copied

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.